# Position on gas station

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word for "position" on gas station, or on car wash, when you can say "I have washed my car on 2nd --position--" or when you say on gas station "I have get fuel from 2nd --position--". I think "position" is not the best word.

Comment: For the gas station, you could say *2nd pump*, and for the car wash, the *2nd bay*. Do you need the same word for both situations?

Comment: In my native language its the same word, but my target was car wash, self-sercice with jet operated specifically. Thank you then

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word used for identifying pump positions in a gas station

- Pump. e.g., pump 1, pump 2, etc
- Island. e.g., Front-Left island, Front-Middle island; island A, island B.

The word used in a car washing facility is *lane*. e.g., lane A, lane B.

The word *lane* is also used for

- bowling alleys
- toll collection gates

Comment: clarifies it all..+1

Answer (score 6):

I used to work at a petrol station (so I know this one) (us Brits use 'petrol' instead of 'gas' which as the fuel is generally considered a liquid...) and we use 'pump 2' or 'pump number 2'. (we only had 1 car wash and that was pre-paid). Often the customer would come in and drop reference to 'pump' what-so-ever, and would just say '2', or 'number 2'.

Comment: Jon is right that Irish and Brits fill up at a petrol station, and always call gasoline 'petrol' and never 'gas'. The reason for the word "gas" in "gasoline" is another question: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/39779/36727